# Проблема с IMAP PHP

Tags: php, imap

```
$imap = imap_open("{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "mail@mail.ru", "password");
while(true){
        $mails_id = imap_search($imap, 'NEW');
        foreach ($mails_id as $num) {
            // Заголовок письма
            $header = imap_header($imap, $num);
            $body = imap_body($imap, $num);
            $fromAdress = mb_decode_mimeheader($header->fromaddress); //Отправитель
            $subject = mb_decode_mimeheader($header->subject); //Заголовок
            $body = strip_tags($body);
            echo $body . PHP_EOL;
        }
        sleep(2);
}
```

Запускаю данный код в консоли (PHP CLI), отправляю на почту сообщение, но скрипт тупо не видит его.
Если вместо флага NEW, например, поставлю ALL, то при запуске скрипта он без проблем спарсит все письма.

Тоесть, новые сообщения отображаются только если перезапустить поток. Я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: У меня centos 7